# Generalized wreath products of commutative algebras with Hopf algebras

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, hopf-algebras, crossed-products

Fix $k$ a commutative ring (or, if more convenient, assume it’s a field or even an algebraically closed field of characteristic 0, which is the case I’m mainly interested in). Let $A$ be a unital commutative $k$-algebra, $\alpha: G \curvearrowright X$ be an action of a group on a set. Then we may consider the tensor product $A^{\otimes X}$ of copies of $A$ with labels from $X$ (as $A$ is unital, this possibly infinite tensor product makes sense). Then $G$ acts on $A^{\otimes X}$ by permuting copies of $A$ via $\alpha$, whence we may form a crossed product $A^{\otimes X} \rtimes G$, known as the generalized wreath product. We observe the following facts:

1. $A^{\otimes X}$ is the representing object of the functor $\mathcal{AbAlg} \ni B \mapsto \mathcal{AbAlg}(A, B^X) \in \mathcal{Set}$ where $\mathcal{AbAlg}$ is the category of unital commutative $k$-algebras and $B^X$ is the Cartesian product of copies of $B$ labeled with elements of $X$.
2. Under this interpretation, it is easy to see that, if a group (more generally a monoid) $G$ acts on $X$, then it induces an action on $A^{\otimes X}$ via Yoneda lemma.
3. $\mathcal{Set}$ embeds as a full subcategory of $\mathcal{CoAlg}$, the category of cocommutative $k$-coalgebras, by sending $X$ to the free $k$-module $kX$, with the coalgebra structure defined so that all elements of $X$ are group-like in $kX$.
4. $B^X$ can be defined purely in terms of the commutative algebra $B$ and the cocommuative coalgebra $kX$. Indeed, for any cocommuative $k$-coalgebra $C$ and commutative $k$-algebra $B$, we may endow the $k$-module $\mathcal{Mod}(C, B)$ with a multiplication $\mu$ given by $\mu(f \otimes g) = \mu_B \circ (f \otimes g) \circ \Delta_C$. One easily sees that this makes $\mathcal{Mod}(C, B)$ into a commutative $k$-algebra (unital if $B$ is). We shall denote this algebra by $\{C, B\}$. One easily sees that $B^X$ is naturally isomorphic to $\{kX, B\}$.

These observations naturally yield the following questions:

1. Is the functor $\mathcal{AbAlg} \ni B \mapsto \mathcal{AbAlg}(A, \{C, B\}) \in \mathcal{Set}$ always representable for cocommutative $C$ instead of just for $C = kX$?
2. Assuming the answer to the first question is yes. By abuse of notations we shall denote the representing object by $A^{\otimes C}$. Again, by Yoneda lemma, if a group (more generally monoid) $G$ acts on $C$, then it acts on $A^{\otimes C}$ and we may therefore form the “generalized wreath product” $A^{\otimes C} \rtimes G$. Does this generalize to Hopf algebras (more generally bialgebras)? That is, if $G$ is a Hopf algebra (more generally bialgebra) and $G$ acts on $C$, does this induce an action of $G$ on $A^{\otimes C}$ so that we may form a smash product $A^{\otimes C} \sharp G$? (For how to make sense of an action of a bialgebra on an algebra or a coalgebra, see, for example, https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/measuring .)

As an extra question, in all of the above is $A$ being commutative necessary? Of course in that scenario, $A^{\otimes X}$, being noncommutative, can’t represent a functor from $\mathcal{AbAlg}$ to $\mathcal{Set}$. However, in that scenario we may consider the free product version of the generalized wreath product, i.e., we may consider $A^{\ast X}$, the free product of copies of $A$ with labels from $X$. $G$ still acts via permuting these copies and so we still have a crossed product $A^{\ast X} \rtimes G$. In that case $A^{\ast X}$ is the representing object for the functor $\mathcal{Alg} \ni B \mapsto \mathcal{Alg}(A, B^X)$ where $\mathcal{Alg}$ is the category of unital $k$-algebras. $\{C, B\}$ can still be defined without $B$ being commutative and is still an algebra, so basically all four facts listed above still hold with suitable modifications. In that case do the two questions listed above also have positive answers? Moreover, there seems to be no need to assume $C$ is cocommuative in that case, as $\{C, B\}$ still makes sense without that and we are not trying to get a commutative algebra out of this anyway. So is the assumption that $C$ is cocommutative removable as well?